# Using System.Drawing.Size to represent width and height as pixels OR percentages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, size

I am in the middle of creating an HtmlHelper method to generate code for various html elements with a `width` and `height`. I have a class like the following simplified example.

```
public class Media {
  public string Url { get; set; }
  public System.Drawing.Size Size { get; set; }
}
```

I will be generating some HTML like the following.

```
<video width="360" height="280">
  <source src="{Media.Url}" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

OR

```
<div style="width:100%;height:50%;background: url({Media.Url});">
  ...
</div>
```

However, I would like to be able to store `width` and `height` as either pixels OR as percentages in my `Media` class. I considered just storing the values as strings, but in my application, I need to be able to multiply and divide the values because I am going to scale the elements at various parts of my site.

Is there something built into the .Net Framework that makes managing sizes as pixels or percentages easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit` lets you store pixels or percentage.

Comment: Thanks. I should have known that.